# Wiring up RJ45 plugs on a basic network extension

Tags: networking, cable, wiring, cat5

I'm trying to wire up a network in an outbuilding. Unfortunately the engineers have left me bar wires so I need to add plugs and sockets. I have a 1gbps socket in the outbuilding that connects to the main network. From here I have a wire that goes to a socket where a computer is to be installed:

Main socket -> sub-socket -> PC

I have tried to wire this up but I'm getting either a "network cable unplugged" message or a 10mbps connection. If I plug the PC directly into the master socket I get full 1GB connection. The problem is clearly with my connections. At the moment the wire connecting the main socket with the sub socket has connection type 568B. Then the sub socket is connected to the PC using a store bought patch cable. Am I using the right connection, what order or wiring should there be in the sub-socket?

Answer (score 2):

They should all match and can be verified by looking at the colors.

568B

wh/or or/wh wh/gr bl/wh wh/bl gr/wh wh/br br/wh

How far is it to the outbuilding?  Gig connections are far less forgiving than 100Mbps connections.  The fact that you get connected at 10 Mbps suggests that it is workmanship in making the connectors and socket (assume you meant outlet).